# Storing the word length in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled as to why I can not store the word length in a javascript array.

I have tried

```
var i = [];
i["length"] = "ABC";
i["len"+"gth"] = "ABC";
```

but both aren't accepted in javascript. Can anyone explain it, and is there a way that I can store the word length in an array as above.

Since some asked for more detail. I am creating a list of words that I need to do a lookup at and find the value to display to the user. My list contains for example:

```
localVars.FunctionDic = [];
localVars.FunctionDic["lastindexof"] = "LastIndexOf(text, textToLocate)";
localVars.FunctionDic["specificindexof"] = "SpecificIndexOf(text, textToLocate, indexNumber)";
localVars.FunctionDic["empty"] = "Empty(text)";
localVars.FunctionDic["length"] = "Length(text)";
```

everything works except for the "length"

and I am using an array since I need to test if the word a user search for is in my array, and if it is display the value, if it is not, show nothing

Comment: The `length` property of an array can only be a number and not a string.

Comment: Why are you using an array when it should be an object?

Comment: try `i.push("ABC".length)`

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are trying to write a string to a property that only allows a number.

> [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length): The length property of an object which is an instance of type Array sets or returns the number of elements in that array. **The value is an unsigned, 32-bit integer** that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

With the limited details in your question it is hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish. It seems like you want to use an array like an object. If that is the case, use an object.

```
var i = {};
i["length"] = "ABC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expected output, I believe you should be using an object not an array.

```js
const FunctionDic = {
  lastindexof: "LastIndexOf(text, textToLocate)",
  specificindexof: "SpecificIndexOf(text, textToLocate, indexNumber)",
  empty: "Empty(text)",
  length: "Length(text)",
};
console.log(FunctionDic["lastindexof"]);
console.log(FunctionDic["specificindexof"]);
console.log(FunctionDic["empty"]);
console.log(FunctionDic["length"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

To store the word length in an array you can do:

```
var i = ["length"]
```

If you want to store the length of a word in an array you can do:

```
var lengthOfHello = "hello".length
var i = [lengthOfHello]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var i = ["ABC"];
console.log(new Array(i[0].length).length);
```

Comment: why not just log `i[0].length` ?

Comment: because it will print the empty array and not the length

Comment: `console.log(i[0].length)` prints `3`, which is the same as your result - not the empty array